# Problems with 2FA in php

Tags: php, google-2fa

So i get a empty respoounse from Google2FA every time i try to validate the key:

It does not matter how much i try i get the same anwser $valid is empty.
And i do not get any errors what so ever!

```php
require("requirements/page.php");
use PragmaRX\Google2FA\Google2FA;

$google2fa = new Google2FA();


if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $secret = $_GET['code'];
    $user_secret = $session->getUserInfo("2fa_secret");
    if ($user_secret == null) {
        header('location: /auth/login');
        die();
    }

    try {
        $valid = $google2fa->verifyKey($user_secret, $secret);
        if ($valid) {
            echo "Input 2FA Code: $secret<br>";
            echo "User's 2FA Secret: $user_secret<br>";
            die("Success: $valid");
        } else {
            echo "Input 2FA Code: $secret<br>";
            echo "User's 2FA Secret: $user_secret<br>";
            die("Failed: $valid");
        }
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        die($ex);
    }
}
```